# Meaning of a symbol for a hole specification in a drawing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

A very simple question, so sorry for this, but I have searched many online docs and cannot find a simple answer. I have a hole specification of 3.4 + 0.13 (picture attached).

What does the +0.13 mean?

[[image: example1]

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken this probaly refers to the **tolerances** (the lower and higher acceptable dimensions of the diameter of the circle).

i.e. : minimum is 3.40mm, and maximum should be 3.53mm

In your particular example you need 4 thru holes within the tolerances stated above [3.40, 3.53].

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Links:

- [Geometric dimensioning and tolerancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing).
- [Datum reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_reference).